# How to create a Rules action set to calculate a sum of integers in a Field Collection?

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I'm having a Field Collection 'My List' with two fields: 'Amount' (integer) and 'Date' (date). I often count the 'Amount' items with Rules like this:

- **Add a variable**: Parameter: Type: Integer, Value: 0, Provides
  variables: Sum
- **Loop** over [node:field-my-list]

  - *Calculate a value*: Parameter: Input value 1: [sum], Input value 2: [my-list:field-amount], Provides variables: Result (result)
  - *Set a data value*: Parameter: Data: [sum], Value: [result]

As setting up this loop every time takes quite some time, I thought that creating a Rules component (action set) would make things a lot easier. I tried this:

- *Data type*: List of field collection item items, *Label*: List, *Usage*: Parameter.
- *Data type*: Integer, *Label*: Sum, *Usage*: Provided.

Creating a loop (Parameter: List: [list], List item: Current list item (list_item)) works, but there's a problem when I try to calculate the value "Sum + List:item". Namely, I can only select *list:0*, *list:1*, *list:2* and *list:3* as "List:item". That doesn't seem to be right.

How can I correctly select an item from the list and use it in the calculation?

Comment: Hey Jeroen, your paragraph near the end with "***Creating a loop (Parameter: List: [list] ...")***" appears tough to understand. If you still remember your question (from over 2 years ago), can you think of something to include an export of your rules component where you were struggling with? PS: I'd also change "action" to "Component" in the title of your question.