# How to calculate a content's type field to store the sum of a referenced content type field?

Tags: nodes, entities

To be more specific, I have a content type "book" and a content type "collection" which has an entity reference field to books (many). How can I calculate the field proce_collection as the sum of all the prices of the books it contains?

I had only a solution due to computed field but have an error when i have to show all collections in a view, cause my code don't get a specific node to calculate.

I am thinking about [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) or anything else, but I do not know the way...

Comment: What's the field name of that "entity reference field to books"? And which Rules Event would you want to use? And yes you're right, you could use Rules for this, actually a piece of cake to do so. Can you include an export of the Rule you have so far, so that we only have to describe the missing piece of it? That way I don't have to write an entire manual to answer your question ...

Comment: hi, i do not have made any rule yet. 
i have content type book, and the book has a field which is the price. 
then i created the content type "collection" which has the node reference filed "books", that is a reference to the content type book. Collection also has a field named collections_price. I want the collections price to be the summary of the prices of each book that it contains (a collection can contain many books).

Comment: Well, in that case I suggest you try to start from [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/232548/39516) ... change all occurrences of "article" to "collection", and change "field-article-details" to the machine name of "entity reference field to books". If you then also add an extra Rules Action (at the start within the loop) like "fetch entity by id", it will make the token available related to your prices (instead of "article-details-item:field-price" ). From then on, you should be close to a working rule. Add it as an update to your question and indicate what's still missing.